# What is the time complexity of the function $5^{\log_3(n)}+n^{1.5}\sum_{j=0}^{log_3n-1}\left(\frac{5}{3^{1.5}}\right)^j$?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

I need to find the $\Theta$ complexity of this function:
$$5^{\log_3(n)}+n^{1.5}\sum_{j=0}^{log_3n-1}\left(\frac{5}{3^{1.5}}\right)^j$$

It shouldn't be too hard, and I already have simplified it, the problem is, the result should be $\Theta\left(n^{1.5}\right)$.

P.S how do you write mathematical expressions on this site??

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, on the following grounds:
$$5^{\log_3(n)}=\left(e^{\log(5)}\right)^{\log_3(n)}=\left(e^{\log(n)}\right)^{\frac{\log(5)}{\log(3)}}=n^{\frac{\log(5)}{\log(3)}}\in\mathcal{O}\left(n^{1.5}\right)$$
and
$$\frac{5}{3^{1.5}}<1\quad\Rightarrow\quad\sum_{j=0}^{\text{anything}}\left(\frac{5}{3^{1.5}}\right)^j\leq\frac{1}{1-\frac{5}{3^{1.5}}}\in\mathcal{O}(1)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! The system works on the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I just don't understand why $n^{\frac{\log(5)}{\log(3)}}\in\Theta\left(n^{1.5}\right)$$. Is a particular reason?

Comment: Yeah they're all big-O upper bounds.

Comment: So can I conclude that also $n^{\frac{\log(5)}{\log(3)}}\in\Theta\left(n^{1.5}\right)$, or would that be incorrect in this case?

Comment: Not necessarily, since $\Theta$ means *exact* asymptotics. The next thing you're doing is $\mathcal{O}(n^{1.5})+\Theta(n^{1.5})\in\Theta(n^{1.5})$.